# Пропали логи из Unity Editor

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

В один прекрасный момент пропало отображение логов в консоле Unity Editor. Сначала сыпались Warning, хотя не менял настройки, потом вообще все перестали отображаться. В коде вывожу логи через Debug.Log(). Ничего глобального в настройках не менял. В Editor Log вроде как отображаются актуальные, хотя точного времени добавления там не нашёл. Сейчас настройки отображения для всех типов логов выставил такими:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переустановил версию Unity и HUB на более новые версии. Ситуация не поменялась. Подскажите, кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была отжата иконка с отображением логов, которая уходила за пределы экрана.